# Scala 3 fails to match a method to an equivalent function signature?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm on Scala 3.2.1, and the code below fails to compile.

```scala
class Test[F[_]] {
  def error(message: => String): F[Unit] = {??? }
  def error(t: Throwable)(message: => String): F[Unit] = {??? }

  def test1(f: String => F[Unit]): Unit = {}
  def test2(f: Throwable => String => F[Unit]): Unit = {}

  test1(error)
  test2(error)
}
```

`test1` line compiles fine, but `test2` breaks with

```text
None of the overloaded alternatives of method error in class Test with types
 (t: Throwable)(message: => String): F[Unit]
 (message: => String): F[Unit]
match expected type Throwable => String => F[Unit]
  test2(error)
```

Substituting `F[Unit]` for just `Unit` works, so I'm suspecting some kind of type erasure issue...? Do I need to put a `ClassTag` somewhere...?

Comment: `test2(error(_))` works but I can't properly explain why the compiler wasn't doing that method-to-function conversion for you in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second overloaded `error`

```
def error(t: Throwable)(message: => String): F[Unit] = {??? }
```

has `=> String` as the type of the second parameter, not `String`. These two types are not the same: first is a potentially side-effecty function that can be re-run multiple times (or not at all), whereas the second is just a pure string.

If you adjust the signature of the second `test` accordingly to

```
def test2(f: Throwable => (=> String) => F[Unit]): Unit = {}
```

it compiles at least with 3.2.0, I don't expect 3.2.1 to be much different here.

Comment: o.O Function *types* can take call-by-name parameters now? The wonders of Scala 3 never cease!

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Why "now"? Function types with by-name parameter types existed in Scala 2 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/ITyksYabRqKOxkL6N3mm2g/2

Comment: @DmytroMitin Fair enough! Regardless, I learned something cool today.